# find page source using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

i have to use code

```
this.setUp("http://www.remax.com/", "*firefox");
selenium.open("/404/index.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/public/pages/searchresults.aspx");
slenium.click("link=Find a RE/MAX Office");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
selenium.selectFrame("REMAX AGENT SEARCH");
selenium.click("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ButtonSearch");
```

to find source of given url but i have to find only few source because here use java script+Frame+Ajax code

i have to use selenium-server2.0.jar

please help me to get source of url using selenium

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for getting the HTML source is correct - I just tested it myself - so I suspect that either Selenium is not configured correctly or there is some other environmental issue.

Could you provide the full exception that you are seeing? Also, can you confirm if the exception is thrown on the `open` or `getHtmlSource` line (or another line)?

Comment: It might help others if you could detail what you had to do to get this to work - in case they have the same problem.